# Pycharm: enable tooltip for variables / names / tokens with mouse hover?

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm looking for something similar to how Visual Studio will show tooltips when hovering the mouse over anything in the editor (type information, method details, other useful information, etc.).  Is this a configurable option in PyCharm? I've yet to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there some screenshots of what you're talking about in Visual Studio? I couldn't find anything after a quick Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available via quick documentation hotkey only, [vote for the issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5999) so that it also works on hover.

Comment: Darn.  Thank you, though. This IDE is a strange combination of many nice features and super obvious features that are missing.  Not worth the $99 at all, though.

Comment: If something doesn't fit your usage patterns from the very start, it doesn't mean that PyCharm is not useful for others. The IDE is keyboard oriented and is aimed for productivity, doing something with mouse is not productive at all, most professional developers don't even touch the mouse during coding and project navigation. While this feature may be useful for the new users, it's value will drop drastically once you learn how to work with the IDE without mouse.

Comment: The fact that the other major IDEs all include this feature by default tells me it is something more than just a useless productivity drain.  When one is learning a new language / framework this feature is _very_ useful.  I must say this arrogant response discourages me -- and no doubt many other prospective customers -- from purchasing PyCharm.  Disappointing, to be sure.

Comment: I agreed that this feature is useful, especially for the new users and that's why we have a request for it in the tracker. It may appear in one of the future versions or someone will create a plug-in adding this functionality. I didn't say that it's useless for all. Don't take my comment so aggressively.