# PyCharm to show declaration bubbles like PyDev in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, pydev, pycharm

In Eclipse/PyDev, when mouse over or click on a class or an object, there will be a bubble with brief declaration code displayed. Can PyCharm do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyCharm can't do the same on mouse hover, you need to press quick documentation lookup shortcut key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on Windows).

Please vote for the [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5999).

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921160/) similar question here.